# How does a programm outputs sound on a low level?

Tags: python, audio, real-time, low-level, synthesizer

I am trying to understand how a programm outputs sound on a low level. I got this question while thinking about programming a **synthesizer**.

Rather than an unchaning file (like *mp3 sound*), a synthesizer creates the sound in *real time*.

Imagine I got a synthesizer programm with GUI:
A slider can change the pitch of a simple sine wave. There has to be some kind of rate in which the programm sends the pitch values to a system **API** which somehow transforms the digital data to analog sound to the speakers.

- How does this whole process works?
- How could I access such API on an Unix system with e.g. python?
- Can you recommend any ressources for further reading on sound synthesis or real time data processing?

Thanks for taking your time to read the question!:)

Comment: May be this is [useful](https://blog.unetstack.net/converting-your-laptop-into-a-janus-modem-using-unetaudio).

Comment: This will be a quite frustrating, but sadly SO is not the best place to ask this question. It is a grand question that spans a few concepts so it is not one that can be answered in a single page. If you are working in python then Pyaudio would be a good place to start as well as the aubio library.

Comment: @fdcpp thanks for answering! PyAudio helps me a lot to understand the basics. Could you roughly name what topics / concepts are involved in the process of my question?

Comment: It's tricky as your question really encompasses all the fundamentals of Digital Audio Signal processing. If you were enrolled in a university I would recommend auditing a course on signal processing or consulting your computer science / informatics department. Outside of that I'd recommend seeking out a community, ideally local where you would be free to discuss / talk around the subject to learn more. This [_awesome list_](https://github.com/faroit/awesome-python-scientific-audio#readme) has a ton that is useful, but you'll have to do a lot of digging to answer specific questions.

Comment: Outside of that, I'd also recommend getting in touch with those who are doing the sort of work you want to do. You can offer to buy them a cup of coffee in return for their time. I would also suggest that `python` is a little unusual for a 'low-level' synthesiser. Typically you'd be working with some C-based. If that doesn't put you off, the [Juce Community](https://forum.juce.com) is good place to start. A correctly tagged question there should garner a bit of attention.

Comment: To set some expectations, going from nothing to being able to understand the fundamentals of DSP I would say is roughly a 6-9 month journey.

Comment: Once you have a coding question of something that you have attempted to implement and that can reduced to a basic working example with as little extra complexity, then SO is a great community. For DSP question, check out the [dsp stackexchange audio tag](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio). Given where you are, I wouldn't expect you to have any questions that haven't already been asked for at least a couple of months.

Comment: @fdcpp Thank you for your time and the detailed answer! You set my expectation to a more realistic goal, but I still keep the interest. I will follow your tip and try to attend signal processing course at my university.

Comment: Yeah C might be better to use, but I am not that comfortable yet. I will keep that in mind and improve my C knowledge!